# Rails 3.2: Validation in a single line for all the fields with fieldname

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a model called video. That model contains 5 attributes. All the field are mandatory. I want to write validation for all the fields at 1 line. The error message should be like "field_name can't be blank"

```
 validates :acodec,:vprofile,:vbitrate,:vwidth,:audio_volume, :presence => {:message=>" can't be blank"}
```

As of now its giving error message like "can't be blank". but i want it with the field name. If you have any idea or suggestions please share.

**UPDATE**

html page:

```
 <%= validation_errors @video.errors['acodec']%>
```

Comment: Instead you can set a message like `These mandatory fields can't be blank`.That would make sense.

Comment: in the form for each text_box i have to display fieldname can't be blank. is there anyway in the model itself to do that?

Comment: Do you always want "fieldname cant be blank"? Or do you want "acodec cant be blank"?

Comment: i want acodec can't be balnk

Comment: If you use `simple_form` or `formtastic` it shows that error for each field, and thus there would be no need to show the field-name (since each faulty field specifies the reason, and is also shown graphically (coloured red). Anyway: can you show us the definition of `validation_errors` or from which gem it is? I am guessing it is a method in your rails app?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your form looks similar to this:

```
<%= form_for(@video) do |f| %>
  <% if @video.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@video.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this video from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @video.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :acodec %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :acodec %>
  </div>
  ...
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The model validation like this:

```
validates :acodec,:vprofile,:vbitrate,:vwidth,:audio_volume, presence: true
```

And the videos_controller:

```
def new
  @video = Video.new
end

def create
  @video = Video.new(video_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @video.save
      format.html { redirect_to @video, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
    end
  end
end
```

This works 100%!

Comment: What does your html Look like? Please add the Code to your question.

Comment: in the errors itelf the message is coming as can't be blank. its not including field name

Comment: my question is to do everything in the model

Comment: Why do you want that??

Answer (score 0):

**Presence** : This helper validates that the specified attributes are not empty. It uses the blank? method to check if the value is either nil or a blank string, that is, a string that is either empty or consists of whitespace.

```
validates :acodec,:vprofile,:vbitrate,:vwidth,:audio_volume, presence: true
```

Refer this Ruby doc of **[Active Record Validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)**

**EDIT**

Try this
**Error Message related Object:**

You can add error messages that are related to the object's state as a whole, instead of being related to a specific attribute. You can use this method when you want to say that the object is invalid, no matter the values of its attributes. Since errors[:base] is an array, you can simply add a string to it and it will be used as an error message.

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
    def a_method_used_for_validation_purposes
        errors[:base] << "This Video is invalid because ..."
    end
end
```

**UPDATE**

If you wish Error with the field name then you have to write something like this:

```
validates_presence_of :acodec,:vprofile,:vbitrate,:vwidth,:audio_volume,  :message => "Your Field Name can't be blank"
```

Still not getting your solution then I suggest you to try **[client-side-validation](http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations)** gem

Comment: for single column we can do like this. but i want to do for multiple column

Comment: @poojaagarwal : that you can do it by  putting another attributes separated by comma